# How to create separate default registers for x,d and y operators in vim?

Tags: vim

If I understand vim correctly, the text that is deleted or yanked goes into the unnamed register (unless a separate register is explicitly created). Is there a way to set separate default registers for the three operators?

Comment: Yes, you can remap them to apply to a specific register. The benefits of the default registers is that multi-line copies are saved in the numbered registers (`:reg` to see them; e.g., the 4th most recent multi-line yank is saved in `"4`); you wouldn't get this functionality with separate registers.

Answer (score 3):

It already works this way. Yanking operations work (by default) with the register "0"; and delete operations use either the register "-" (small delete), or the register "1" (linewise delete) with the subsequent shift of old values "1" -> "2" -> ... -> "9".

A so-called "unnamed" register is, in fact, a pointer to the register used last time. It has no value of its own.

Hence, use `"0p` to put the last yanked text, `"1p` to put the last deleted line(s) etc.